# How to use Google Sheets Drop-Down Menu to Show Full Name Store Short Name

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I have several fields in a Google sheet that have reoccurring long names that we would like to abbreviate, like organization names, account numbers, etc.

They all fit the example of filling in an address where we have a field for the state. We want a drop-down menu that shows the state’s full name and when selected it puts the state’s postal code in the field.

Let’s say Sheet1 has “Name” in column A and “State” in column B. In Sheet2 we have “Postal Code” in column A and “State” (name) in column B. It looks like this.

```
Sheet1
     A     |    B    |
1. Name    | State   |
2. Charlie | MN      |
3. Jane    | NY      |
4. John    | -->Drop-down goes here<--

Sheet 2
     A     |    B         |
1. Code    | State        |
2. AL      | Alabama      |
3. AK      | New York     |
4. AZ      | Arizona      |
5. AR      | Arkansas     |
6. CA      | California   |
```

I would like a drop-down in the “State” field in Sheet1 that shows the full state name (or both the postal code and name) and when selected puts the correct postal code in the cell.

I have worked through examples I found here that let me populate multiple fields after selecting something from a drop-down. I have used Sheets "Data Validation" to make the drop-downs and `vlookup` from the examples to populate the fields. I have NOT found anything that shows me how to select a full name from a drop-down and put the abbreviation in the cell.

In other words, how do I show a drop-down from column B, but input the data from column A?

Comment: I'm sorry about the Sheet 1 and 2 mess. I tried to post an image and that was a no-go and then I tried formating a text version, which looked fine until I posted it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit help Max.

Comment: so, in other words, you want to have this in the dropdown: Alabama,New York,Arizona... and when you select something it will show only AL,NY,AZ,... ? if so, its not possible

Comment: You got some bigger problems if AK returns the value =  "New York"